# RANKX Function producing Cartesian product in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, cartesian-product

I'm running into a Cartesian product issue when combining a RANKX function with columns from a particular table in my model.

I'm connecting to an on-premise data warehouse with version 2.53.4954.621 of Power BI Desktop. I have four tables in my model, Sales, Region, Sales Goal, and Calendar.

All the tables are joined to Sales, so I'll provide the relevant table structure for that entity.

```
Sales:
rowid
date
rep_id
region_id
sales
discount
company number
RepRegionKey (merging of rep_id and region_id)
```

Here are the relationships defined between my tables

```
1. From Sales (date) to Calendar (Date), *:1, Single direction
2. From Sales (region_id) to Region (id), *:1, Both directions
3. From Sales (RepRegionKey) to Sales Goal (RepRegionKey), *:1, Both directions
```

I have a few measures defined on the Sales table as well. I'm not sure which of them may be important so I'll list them all.

**YTD Sales** = `CALCULATE(SUM('Sales'[sales]) - SUM('Sales'[discount]))`

**YE Sales Goal** =

```
CALCULATE(SUM('Sales Goal'[sales_goal]))
```

**$ YTD Goal vs YTD Sales** =

```
CALCULATE([YTD Sales] - [YE Sales Goal])
```

**% YTD Goal vs YTD Sales** = `DIVIDE([$ YTD Goal vs YTD Sales],[YE Sales Goal])`

**Diff Rank** = `RANKX(ALL('Sales Goal'[rep_id]),CALCULATE([% YTD Goal vs YTD Sales]),,,DENSE)`

The Cartesian Product arises when I add the **Diff Rank** measure to a table visualization containing 'Region'[region_desc] (or any of the 'Region' fields except company_number, which only has one value in the table).

Observe in the picture below how the region_desc field can cohabit a table (leftmost table in the picture) peacefully with the % YTD Goal vs YTD Sales measure, upon which the RANX function is built. Additionally, in the middle table, you see that the RANKX function works correctly in the absence of the region_desc field. In the final table on the right, however, the Cartesian product appears when combining the RANKX and region_desc fields.

[RANKX Cartesian Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXoG5.png)

I would prefer to see the accurate Rank for each Rep, like so:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZBu8.png)

Are my relationships incorrect, or do I perhaps need to adjust the RANKX definition?

These are the definitions I have tried, with varying degrees of failure:

--- WORKS WITHOUT REGION_DESC

```
Diff Rank = RANKX(ALL('Sales Goal'[rep_id]),CALCULATE([% YTD Goal vs YTD Sales],ALLSELECTED('Region'[region_desc])),,,DENSE) 

Diff Rank = RANKX(ALL('Sales Goal'[rep_id]),CALCULATE([% YTD Goal vs YTD Sales],ALL(Region[region_desc])),,,DENSE)

Diff Rank = RANKX(ALL('Sales Goal'[rep_id]),CALCULATE([% YTD Goal vs YTD Sales],FILTER(ALL(Region[region_desc]),[region_desc]<>"BUBBA")),,,DENSE)

Diff Rank = RANKX(ALL('Sales Goal'[rep_id]),CALCULATE([% YTD Goal vs YTD Sales],ALLEXCEPT('Region','Region'[region_desc])),,,DENSE)
```

--- DOES NOT WORK WITHOUT REGION_DESC

```
Diff Rank = RANKX('Sales Goal',CALCULATE([% YTD Goal vs YTD Sales],ALLEXCEPT('Region','Region'[region_desc])),,,DENSE)

Diff Rank = RANKX('Sales Goal',CALCULATE([% YTD Goal vs YTD Sales],ALLSELECTED('Region'[region_desc])),,,DENSE)

Diff Rank = RANKX('Sales Goal',CALCULATE([% YTD Goal vs YTD Sales],ALL('Region'[region_desc])),,,DENSE)

Diff Rank = RANKX('Sales Goal',CALCULATE([% YTD Goal vs YTD Sales],FILTER(ALL(Region[region_desc]),[region_desc]<>"BUBBA")),,,DENSE)

Diff Rank = RANKX(DISTINCT('Sales Goal'[rep_id]),CALCULATE([% YTD Goal vs YTD Sales]),,,DENSE)

Diff Rank = RANKX(VALUES('Sales Goal'[rep_id]),CALCULATE([% YTD Goal vs YTD Sales]),,,DENSE)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your table, and possible a mockup of your desired outcome?

Comment: Done! Thank you. I also adjusted the statement of the problem to reflect the current state of affairs, which has changed.

Comment: What happens if you add your region to your ALL() ?

Diff Rank = RANKX(ALL('Sales Goal'[rep_id],'Region'[region_desc]),CALCULATE([% YTD Goal vs YTD Sales]),,,DENSE)

Comment: I get the following error: "All column arguments of the ALL/ALLNOBLANKROW function must be from the same table."

Comment: @futurenow, the reason you have this problem is incorrect data model. Sales Goal must be a fact table, not a dimension. It should have the same keys as your Sales table, and share the same dimensions. Also, get rid of the rep-region key - you already have rep and region keys in your fact table, and it's a simptom of the design mistake I mentioned. Once you fix the model, your DAX measures will be streightforward.

Comment: @RADO, how can I make Sales Goal share the dimensions of Sales, when Sales Goal necessarily doesn't have the same granularity (rowid, which is the order number, and date, which is the date of the order) as Sales?

Comment: rowid you don't need in Sale Goals, it's irrelevant (it's only used to analyze sale orders). Date (Calendar) is indeed on different grain, but you have several choices here. For example, you can use the first (or last) day of period (say, month) as a date key in Sale Goals. Such structure will work properly on a monthly level. It won't work on a daily level, obviously, but that's not your objective. Or, if you want to be fancy, read this article: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/budget-and-other-data-at-different-granularities-in-powerpivot/